# Suggestions to create user name/password pair to create a custom registration page?

Tags: android, hashmap, registration

Currently I have a text file where I store username/password on to a text file!

I want to store hashmap of username->{password,other user info}.

This is just initial prototype, finally I will use a SQL database to store these values.

I did some google searches and people are mostly talking about connecting to sql database, is it easier than attemping to store it temporarily ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try marshalling/unmarshalling the data as JSON using a library like [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). The data would be stored on disk. This approach will be lighter weight than SQLite for your prototype and shouldn't require too much throwaway code.